# Telegram API. Не могу понять что и куда отправлять

Tags: python, api, telegram

Можно простой пример того как проверить зарегистрирован ли телефон функцией [auth.checkPhone](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.checkPhone)? Либо пример любой другой функции из api телеграмма (не bot api).